# bootstrap 4 tooltip conflict with JquerySmoothState

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 tooltip for anchor, and jquery smoothstate for ajax load, but if I click a link, the tooltip is hanging on the next page, here a screen capture:

[image]

is there any fix for this ?

***Update***

here the demo link:
http://0o.mrnazi.com:81/bs4/index.html

[image]

Im using this jquery plugin: https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js
no console error

Comment: Post the code related to the issue. You don't want answers based on guesswork.

Comment: oops sorry, i will upload some test page for the example

Comment: here the demo http://0o.mrnazi.com:81/bs4/index.html

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have to open issues on GitHub...

Comment: i'm looking for temporary workaround

Answer (score 0):

I'm quoting from the official documentation:

> Sometimes it is necessary to use Bootstrap plugins with other UI frameworks. In these circumstances, namespace collisions can occasionally occur. If this happens, you may call `.noConflict` on the plugin you wish to revert the value of.

And the code example given there is this:

```html
  var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict() // return $.fn.button to previously assigned value
  $.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton            // give $().bootstrapBtn the Bootstrap functionality
```

So, your task would be to dig into the [bootstrap.js](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.js) file and find out which plugin there is doing the tooltips. And then apply the `.noConflict` method to that.

Also note: This will certainly be associated with the [popper.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.js) file/plugin which Bootstrap uses as a dependency for handling tooltips.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/javascript/#no-conflict

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide the active tooltip when the page transition begin.

You can use the `onStart` function from smoothState.js (which runs once a page load has been activated. - https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js#onstart).

Add the following code to your smoothState.js plugin options:

```
onStart: {
    duration: 250,
    render: function($container) {

            // hide the tooltips
            $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip('hide');

            smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();

    }
 },
```